# How to indicate type of a variable and an array we know for sure that the value of the variable is in the array in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-native

Do you guys know somehow to indicate type of a variable we know for sure that the value of this variable is in an array in Typescript?

For exemple, I want to display a list of tabs on a tabs bar:

```
const TabsBar= ({tabs}: {tabs: string[]}) => {
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<string>(tabs[0]) //the active tab by default is the first tab in array of tabs

    useEffect(() => {
        setActiveTab(tabs.find(tab => tab === activeTab))//give error Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable                      
//to parameter of type 'string'. How to define type of "tabs" and "activeTab" so that the error disappear?
    }, [tabs, activeTab])
        
    ...
}
```

And also in the case that a tab has this form `{id:number;title:string}`, how to make `tabs.find(tab => tab.id === activeTab.id)` without error?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific problems are related to the fact that arrays might be empty, in order to make Typescript like you, do 2 things:

let's say `Tab` is your type, could be `string` as well.

1. use this syntax to tell typescript that there's at least one element in the array.

```
   const TabsBar = ({ tabs }: { tabs: [Tab, ...Tab[]] }) => {
      // implementation
   }
```

2.handle the case in which `find` returns undefined.

```
   ...
   useEffect(() => {
      const selected = tabs.find(...) //now selected is of type `Tab | undefined`
      if (!selected) throw Error("Unexpected tab") // this shouldn't happen
      // any future usage of `selected` would be Tab without undefined
      setActiveTab(selected)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do so :

```
const TabsBar= ({tabs}: {tabs: string[]}) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<string>(tabs[0]) 
  useEffect(() => {
    const result = tabs.find(tab => tab === activeTab);
    if (result) {setActiveTab(result))};
    }, [tabs, activeTab])
}
```

Then, it should be ok, although, it doesn't exactly reply to your request.

Otherwise, you would have to put an exclamation mark (non-null assertion operator) here :

```
    tabs.find(tab => tab === activeTab)!
```